# NodeJS EC2 low performance

Tags: node.js, rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm hosting a REST API based on NodeJS on Amazon Web Services.
According the following code :

```
var http = require("http");
var PORT = 8080; 

var requestCount = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    console.log("Reqs/s: " + requestCount);
    requestCount = 0;
}, 1000);


http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    requestCount++; 
    response.writeHead(200, 'Ok');  
    response.end();
}).listen(PORT);
```

My NodeJS application can't exceed 4000 requests per second.
I tried to increase the limit of file/socket allowed per second with this command line :

```
ulimit -n 100000
```

But the behavior still the same.
I tried with a t2.micro (1 cpu, 1Gb ram) and a m4.xlarge (4 cpus, 16GB ram ) same behavior too.

There is an other tricks/tips to increase the number of request per second ?

Thank you,

Comment: Nodejs being single-threaded, the numer of cpus on the instance has no impact at all. Have you identified the bottleneck (I/O, cpu, ram?). How are you firing the requests to the server?

Comment: In the t2.micro the cpu seems the bottleneck (around 99%) but with the m4.xlarge only 50% was used. I request my NodeJS application server with 5 dedicated server (t2.micro too)

Comment: Any progress on this?

Comment: I tried the same code on a t2.nano (aws linux), I can only get about 100rps